# Media Queries doesn't work when there is a lot of them

Tags: css, media-queries

When I write media and after check it - it works! But when I write 5-6 media queries and after I check them, they are doesn't work!

I try the next code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) and (max-height: 1024px) {...}

@media screen and (max-width: 1366px) and (max-height: 768px) {...}

@media screen and (max-width: 1400px) and (max-height: 1050px) {...}

@media screen and (max-width: 1440px) and (max-height: 900px) {...}
```

Here, in the StackOverflow I saw the post like my, with the code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1920px), screen and (max-height: 1080px) {....}
```

But it doesn't work too. What is the problem?

**UPDATE**

I use it on IE8 with the JS plugins respond.js and css3-mediaqueries.js

Comment: Any browser information ?

Comment: dont forgot to this meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Guessing overlapping rules ... I'll have a go at a codepen

Comment: @Samoth all browsers.
I have this meta. When I have only 1 query - it works. But multiple - doesn't!

Comment: I have a similar one working - http://codepen.io/elliz/pen/lynEt - but only using two at moment ... adding more ...

Answer (score 0):

I have this working ... though getting the exact window where each triggers is tricky.

---

EDIT:
The order of the media queries is important - and as you have overlapping height and widths you will be in a world of pain. If you reverse the order of your queries you will get more working.

remember that the last matching rule will win.

if you have boxes that are inside each other, get the order right and you will be fine

if you have boxes that overlap, there will be zones that do not get targetted as you wish.

---

You are better going mobile first and using MIN instead of MAX on widths and heights. Also y ou are better at choosing your breakpoints based on your content, not on arbitrary screen resoultions - as there are so many out there you are never going to get them all.

http://codepen.io/elliz/pen/lynEt

```
<div class="a">
  Test<br>
  width = <span class="w">resize me</span><br>
  height = <span class="h">resize me</span>

  <p>Breakpoints:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>500w 500h - red (go to 499w, 499h to see)</li>
    <li>600w 400h - green (go to 599w, 399h to see)</li>
    <li>700w 550h - gold (go large to see)</li>
  </ul>
</div>

.a {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding:10px 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) and (max-height: 550px) {
  .a {background: goldenrod;}  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) and (max-height: 400px) {
  .a {background: green;}  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) and (max-height: 500px) {
  .a {background: red;}  
}

// requires jQuery
$(window).resize(function (){
  showsizes();
});

$(window).ready(function (){
  showsizes();
});


function showsizes(){
    var w = $(window);
  $(".w").text(w.width());
  $(".h").text(w.height());
}
```

Comment: I work in IE8 with css3-mediaqueries.js. It doesn't work

Comment: Why not use respond.js? https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond . I am testing in latest chrome. Try it with respond.js instead ... but you need to change the order of the queries: biggest width first. But as you have overlapping size boxes you will not get all things triggering as you want.

Comment: Key issue - reverse the order of your @media statements: 1440 first, 1280 last

Comment: Do you know what is my problem? When I use many media statements with the same width but with the different height query trouble.

For example:

     media screen and (max-width: 1280px), screen and and (max-height: 800px) {height: 50px;}


      media screen and (max-width: 1280px), screen and and (max-height: 960px) {height: 100px;}


      media screen and (max-width: 1280px), screen and and (max-height: 900px) {height: 150px;}

It takes 150px in 800 height of screen instead of 50px

Comment: post an example on codepen.com or similar code site for us to look at.

Comment: Look at how frameworks such as Twitter's http://getbootstrap.com/ do it for their responsive bits. Use and adapt.

Comment: www.orkhanalizade.com/ie it's on bootstrap. But in IE8 looks very bad and doesn't responsive. Thats why I use respond.js.

Comment: Sorry cannot test on IE8, non a mac today. Read my previous comments and try it out. View the js console to see if any errors are triggering. Good luck.